# Editando conteúdo da página via JQuery e deixando fixo

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de saber o método de editar a pagina e deixar o conteúdo que eu editei fixo lá para sempre, como se fosse uma postagem.

Eu já tentei isso:

```
<style type="text/css">
.aprovado{
    background-color: #060;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.reprovado{
    background-color: #f22;
    color: #E2E2E2;
}
</style>
    < script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js"></script>
    < script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $("#btn").click(function(){

        $("#resposta").removeClass();

        var nome = $("#txtnome").val();
        var n1 = parseFloat ($("#txtn1").val());
        var n2 = parseFloat ($("#txtn2").val());

        var media = (n1 + n2) / 2;           
        $("#resposta").html(nome + ", " + media);

        if(media >= 7){
            $("#resposta").addClass("aprovado");
        }else{
            $("#resposta").addClass("reprovado");
        }


    });

});
</script>
<h3>Ver Dados do Aluno</h3>
<form>
Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" id="txtnome" />
<br /><br />
Nota1: <input type="text" name="n1" id="txtn1" />
<br /><br />
Nota2: <input type="text" name="n2" id="txtn2" />
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Enviar Dados" id="btn" />
</form>
<div id="resposta"></div>
```

Funciona, mais ao atualizar a página some, mas como faço para gravar as alterações apenas usando AJAX e jQuery?

Comment: Não está claro o que você está perguntando. Elabore, ou sua pergunta provavelmente será fechada. Qual exatamente o seu problema? O que você já tentou?

Comment: Será que alguem poderia mesmo ajudar, é urgente

Comment: O Ajax serve para fazer requisições cliente-servidor, quando ele altera a classe css através de uma função, ela é executada apenas no browser, e quando você recarregar, irá voltar ao normal, o que está programado apenas no html.
Procure saber a diferença entre executar no lado do cliente e no lado do servidor.
O que você postou não tem nada de ajax, somente de Jquery.

Comment: Você quer deixar fixo uma mudança feita pelo usuário na página ou por você no código?

Comment: Pelo usuário, ele vai estar no painel administrador vai ter a opção de editar conteudos de uma pagina, ele clica em especificado conteudo, digita o novo texto a ser mostrado, e depois fica fixo na página.

Comment: Não é possível fazer isso só com javascript/jquery. Você precisa de uma linguagem que rode no servidor, e possivelmente de um banco de dados.

Comment: Banco de dados não é problema, mais que tipo de linguagem você quer dizer? Atualmente conheço js,css,html,python e php.

Comment: Python e php servem. Você precisa de um webserver, que receba o que foi modificado e salve o resultado (em disco ou num bd).

Comment: Ok, ajudou muito, obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, pelo que entendi você está tentando editar um conteúdo em HTML apenas com Javascript, porém o que você queria fazer é gravar um dado importante, como uma flag, dizendo que tal aluno está aprovado ou reprovado.

Sinto muito mas você precisará utilizar algum recurso para gravar estes dados, como um Banco de Dados, e para interagir com ele você não poderá utilizar apenas Javascript necessitando da utilização de alguma outra linguagem como PHP, Ruby, etc.

O Javascript atua apenas no navegador, esta atualização que você está fazendo é visível no navegador porém não é gravado nenhum registro em algum lugar para identificar se o aluno está ou não aprovado, caso você queira realizar a atualização dessa maneira, funciona, porém você terá que utilizar outro recurso, como o Ajax, que enviaria essa informação para outra página, em PHP por exemplo, e esta realizaria a atualização no seu BD.

Boa sorte amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer salvar as alterações para serem lidas depois em qualquer lugar que acesse um link para sua página web, tem de fazer isso que o matheus_auler falou. Já se você só precisar disso em um navegador e por um período de tempo curto, pode utilizar [HTML5 - Local Storage](http://zenorocha.com/html5-local-storage/). Com ele você irá salvar os dados no navegador/browser e não poderá acessar de outro lugar.

Comment: Por favor, tente colocar algum código de exemplo.